# Find and remove sub-directories without error?

Tags: bash, find, directory, rm

I need to find a way to remove sub-directories from within a particular directory without receiving an error if no sub-directories exist. This command will successfully remove sub-directories if they exist

```
find /path/to/dir/* -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But if none exist I will get this error:

> find: /path/to/dir/*: No such file or directory

Also, I am using the `find` instead of just plain `rm` because there are too many directories for `rm` to handle and they must be handled individually with `find`.

Also I noticed that `find /path/to/dir/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;` with no wildcard actually removes the *dir* directory as well.

Comment: If the problem with using `rm` is `ARG_MAX` from the glob, find is going to have the same problem since that is a global limitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-mindepth` parameter from find, to prevent it from matching `.` in the target directory. This should resolve your issues.

```
find /path/to/dir/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: Adding mindepth did solve my problem. Thanks! By the way, with + at the end I get "Argument list too long" error. This will work if + is changed to \; See [Using ; vs + with exec in find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-vs-with-exec-in-find/6085237#6085237).

Comment: @KoreyHinton - I understand the difference, but thought that `find` would split it up based on `ARG_MAX` like `xargs` would.